# Solving an integral for the characteristic function of $xy$

Tags: solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I have to solve the following integral: $\int_{[0,1]} χ_{\mathbb{Q}}(xy) dλ(x)$.

Obviously, $χ_{\mathbb{Q}}(xy) = 1$ if $xy \in \{xy \text{ with } x, y \in [0,1]: xy \in \mathbb{Q}\} =:A$. Furthermore A is a λ-null set, as it is a subset of the rational numbers. 
Is it allowed to say, that $\int_{[0,1]} χ_{\mathbb{Q}}(xy) \text{ }dλ(x) = \int_{[0,1]} 0 \text{ }dλ(x)$, as the two integrals are only different on a λ-null set? 
I am a bit confused by the $y$ in the characteristic function, because I haven't seen this before.

Thanks for any advice/help

Comment: Here $y$ is just some number as far as I can see. _If_ $y\in\Bbb Q$ the proof seems right; if $y$ is irrational you can't say $A\subset\Bbb Q$ as you do, but $A$ is still a null set because (if $y\ne0$) it is _countable_.

Comment: You are not allowed to say what you did unless you provide a reason.  Your set $A$ depends on $y$, right?  Are all of those sets $\lambda$-null?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was thinking about that, but why isn't A a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ - i thought by including the condition $xy \in \mathbb{Q}$ A would always be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I thought about this problem and now I see the mistakes I made: What I really need to show is that for a fixed $y \in [0,1]$  $x\cdot y$ is rational for λ almost all $x \in [0,1]$. Therefore I really need to show, that $A_y := \{x \in [0,1]: xy \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a λ-null set for all $y \in [0,1]$. As @DavidC.Ullrich wrote, it's possible to show that for all $y ≠ 0$.

Comment: True, $A\subset \Bbb Q$ by definition. My comment wasn't quite right - your answer is less right than realized: What matters here is not whether $A$ is a null set; what matters is whether $\{x:xy\in A\}$ is a null set.